# timestamp to php from timestamp array

Tags: php, xml, api, timestamp

Hi guys i am really new to php and i am trying to convert the timestamp from an xml array but with no sucess , i read everything i found but still can find the way can you please help ?

I am using this code to decode an xml api output

```
$mysongs = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/test/xml/');
$timestamp = $mysongs->item->timestamp;
$playtime = date("Y-d-m G-i-s",$timestamp);
```

If i echo $timestamp it works fine, $playtime doesn't...

Tried with :

```
echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

&

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $wra);
```

&

```
echo '<timeplayed>' . date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $mysongs->item->timestamp) . '</timeplayed>';
```

Still no luck.. Time is not showing.. If i use this example

```
echo '<timeplayed>' . date('Y-m-d G:i:s', (1365532902)) . '</timeplayed>';
```

it works fine.. What am i doing wrong here ?

### Update

Finally i found it.. it needed to cast the $timestamp as integer for the date to decode properly as euxneks sugested..

So right code should be

```
$timestamp = intVal ($mysongs->item->timestamp);
```

and then

```
    $playtime = date("Y-d-m H-i-s",($timestamp));
```

& finally `echo ($playtime);` and it works fine...

Thanks everyone for your replys problem solved

Comment: When you echo $timestamp, what does it output? A number or a date?

Comment: it outputs a string like this one "1365532902" (if im not wrong this is unix time format right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you need to cast your result as an integer (it's been a while since I've used simplexml but I'm pretty sure it doesn't automatically type the values received):

http://php.net/intval

Also, strtotime might work too :)

http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: Thanks euxneks for help but i don't know how to use intvar.. i will have a look on your link..

Comment: You were right :) it needed "intVal" for the unix time format

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely missing `strtotime` function, here is an example:

```
$str = '04/09/2013';
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($str));

echo $date;
```

This will output:

```
2013-04-09 00:00:00
```

Updated

Since strtotime is alread used, what about using:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ($timestamp));
```

Comment: Hi Fabio & thanks for reply, i tried this but it shows incorent data "1970-01-01 01-00-00" the problem is when i use this $timestamp = $mysongs->item->timestamp; as time and not a fixed value..

Comment: What is data format in xml document? Is the time `01-00-00` correct?

Comment: No its unix format example :1365532902  The php script that outputs the xml is using ['timestamp'] = strtotime to encode it..

Comment: Does `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp));` give as output `1970-01-01-01 01-00-00`?

Comment: Fabio finally i found it, yes if i use strtotime it will output 1970-01-01-01 etx because time format is already strtotime encoded so nothing to output, it just needed to cast the results as integer to work without of course strtotime..